# Passing data to a web from from a aspx.cs file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have this input in my web form:

```
 <input type="text" id="keywordSearch" value="Keyword" runat="server" />
```

How do I get this data into there (it's from my Page_Load):

```
 string keywords = "This is my keywords!";
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, why are you not using built in TextBox control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missed the part about it being a regular HTML control:

```
keywordSearch.Value = keywords;
```

Comment: The above doesn't work if I don't use a textbox control. How do I do it without using asp:Textbox?